# Websocket - Waiting for a http request callback to execute before next pusher event

Tags: node.js, websocket, callback, pusher

So I'm working with websockets to process data from website's API. For every new event I also send some http requests back to the website in order to obtain more data. Up untill now everything has worked fine, but now that I started using async requests to speed it up a bit things got a bit different. My code used to process one event and then move on to the next one (these events come in extremely quick - around 10 per second) but now it just seems to ignore the async (non blocking) part and move on to the next event and that way it just skips over half of the code. Note that the code works fine outside the Pusher. I'm using the  'pusher-client' module. My code looks like this:

```
var Request = require("request");
var requestSync = require('sync-request');
var Pusher = require('pusher-client');

var events_channel = pusher.subscribe('inventory_changes');
events_channel1.bind('listed', function(data)
{
    var var2;
    //Async request (to speed up the code)
    function myFunction(callback){
        request("url", function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) 
            {
                result = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(body));
                return callback(null, result);
            } 
            else 
            {
                return callback(error, null);
            }
        });
    }

    myFunction(function(err, data){
        if(!err)
        {
            var2 = data
            return(data);
        }
        else
        {
            return(err);
        }
    });


    //The part of the code below waits for the callback and the executes some code
    var var1 = var2;

    check();
    function check() 
    {
        if(var2 === var1)
        {
            setTimeout(check, 10);
            return;
        }
        var1 = var2;

        //A CHUNK OF CODE EXECUTES HERE (connected to the data from the callback)
    }
});
```

In conclusion the code works, but not inside the pusher due to the pusher skipping the asynchronous request. How would I make the pusher wait for my async request to finish, before processing the next event (I have no idea)? If you happen to know, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a queue to handle events one after another. I'm curious how it worked before, even without `Pusher` you'd have to implement some queue mechanism for it.

```js
const eventsQueue = []

events_channel1.bind('listed', function(data) {
  eventsQueue.push(data)
  handleNewEvent()
})

let processingEvent = false
function handleNewEvent() {
  if (processingEvent) return // do nothing if already processing an event
  processingEvent = true
  const eventData = eventsQueue.shift() // pick the first element from array
  if (!eventData) return // all events are handled at the moment
  ... // handle event data here
  processingEvent = false
  handleNewEvent() // handle next event
}
```

Also, you should call `clearTimeout` method to clear your timeout when you don;t need it anymore.

And it's better to use promises or `async/await` instead of callbacks. Your code will be much easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've bumped into an error saying: _"processingEvent = false; SyntaxError: Rest parameter may not have a default initializer"_. If you know the cause please let me know :)

Comment: Remove `...` before `processingEvent = false` line, I just added it as a placeholder for your code

Comment: For some reason the _"// handle event data here"_ line will only execute once. Also it seems that the function will only call itself once (at the begining) and then it will only be called by the pusher even if there are more elements to process.

Comment: It is executed once for each event, it is also called at the end of its body

Comment: Well that's odd. I put a _console.log(1);_ in there and it only displayed it once, while if i put one 1 line below the _"if (processingEvent) {return}"_ line it would be executed twice. If I put it as the top line in the function it executes for every event. It seems that there is something not quite right with the _processingEvent_ variable.

Comment: `processingEvent = false; handleNewEvent()` - this is supposed to run when your handler is finished of course (i.e. in your `check` callback), otherwise, the event is still processing and you shouldn't set this flag to `false`. I assume you just inserted your handler at `...` place. Probably should have made it more clear

Comment: This works now. But when I tried to implement some IF statements above the async request code and it stopped working. For every if statement I also added an else statement: -"else{processingEvent = false; handleNewEvent(); return;}"_ Again it only seems to execute once. How could I get this to work?

Comment: Nevermind, found the problem: Just added _processingEvent = false;_ into the _if(!eventData)_  statement. Works fine now. Thanks for you help :)